# Returning a computed list from a function

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

```
Nsteps[N_] := (
  P = 1;
  For[iter = 1, iter < 81, iter++, 
    sigma = 1;
    a = 
      Accumulate @ 
        Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {N, 2}], {0, 0}];
    Clear[theta, x];
    theta[i_] := theta[i] = theta[i - 1] + a[[i]];
    x[i_] := x[i] = x[i - 1] + P {Cos[theta[i]], Sin[theta[i]]};
    theta[0] = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
    x[0] = {0, 0};
    For[step = 1, step <= N, step++, r[iter, step] = x[step];]]
    Print[pathlength = Table[Sum[Norm[r[s, i]], {i, 1, N}], {s, 1, 80}]]
    Return[pathlength])

N_steps[500]
meandistance = pathlength/80
N_steps[450]
meandistance1 = pathlength/80
```

The last four lines produce outputs.

I am trying to run the function `Nsteps` with multiple different numbers of steps. I want to find each corresponding path length and mean distance. How can I write a function that returns each path length and save it to a new list? So in the end, when I display the new list, I can see each path length for 500 and 450.

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you ask for is easy, but first your code must be cleaned up. The clean-up will not only fix some bugs, it will improve performance. Still the code presented here is far from optimal.

```
Clear[Nsteps]
With[{P = 1},
  Nsteps[n_, s_] :=
    Block[{iter, a, theta, x, step, r},
      theta[i_] := theta[i] = theta[i - 1] + a[[i]];
      x[i_] := x[i] = x[i - 1] + P {Cos[theta[i]], Sin[theta[i]]};
      Do[
        a =
          Accumulate @ 
            Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, 2}], {0, 0}];
        DownValues[theta] = Last[DownValues[theta]];
        DownValues[x] = Last[DownValues[x]];
        theta[0] = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
        x[0] = {0, 0};
        Do[r[iter, step] = x[step], {step, n}],
        {iter, s}];
      Table[Sum[Norm[r[j, i]], {i, n}], {j, s}]]]
```

Then

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{s = 6},
  lengths = Table[Nsteps[i, s], {i, 40, 55, 5}];
  meandistance = lengths/s];
```

produces

> ```
> {{134.003, 228.392, 175.535, 374.017, 174.427, 131.035}, 
>  {189.435, 335.657, 279.026, 257.402, 159.394, 338.826}, 
>  {160.753, 356.551, 409.49, 421.055, 514.6, 269.301}, 
>  {359.12, 435.68, 342.374, 322.592, 337.342, 627.565}}
>
> {{22.3338, 38.0654, 29.2559, 62.3361, 29.0711, 21.8392}, 
>  {31.5724, 55.9428, 46.5043, 42.9003, 26.5657, 56.471}, 
>  {26.7921, 59.4252, 68.2484, 70.1759, 85.7667, 44.8834}, 
>  {59.8534, 72.6133, 57.0624, 53.7654, 56.2237, 104.594}}
> ```